# Utilizar teclado virtual ajuda a segurança?

Tags: segurança, teclado, keylogger

A utilização de teclados virtuais (igual ao da pesquisa do Google) previne que os dados digitados sejam coletados por Keyloggers? Se sim existe algum teclado virtual que possam indicar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essas soluções são bem ingênuas. Quando alguém usa um recurso desses para dar mais segurança ou não sabe o que está fazendo ou está apenas praticando marketing.

Teclados virtuais podem ser capturados facilmente. Quando uma máquina está comprometida nada que está nela pode ser usado com confiança. Não adianta usar artifícios para evitar a coleta de informação sensível.

É verdade que muitos *keyloggers* não são sofisticados e só capturam o teclado mesmo. Mas se quer segurança não pode confiar na sorte da máquina infectada estar com um *keylogger* ruim.

Eu não recomendaria algum software desses porque eles apenas criam ilusão de segurança, mesmo os mais sofisticados que tentam bloquear a captura de tela ou outras proteções. Qualquer solução que funcione, deixa de funcionar quando *hackers* quiserem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Diria o mesmo de alguns softwares de proteção a acesso bancário feitos no brasil. Mil complicações **artificiais** pro usuário legítimo, e uma piada pra quem realmente quer copiar as credenciais.

Answer (score 6):

Um teclado virtual poderia ser considerado um dos elemento que compõem um arsenal necessário para incrementar o nível de segurança de uma solução.

Ele pode ao menos livrar o usuário de uma categoria de vazamento de informações, que são os *keyloggers* baseados na captura de teclas. Se o usuário não pressiona uma tecla, um *keylogger* puro não consegue capturar o *input*.

Entretanto, se o *malware* consegue também capturar os eventos do clique e as imagens da tela, então ele conseguirá identificar onde o usuário clicou no teclado virtual. Para evitar a descoberta da senha mesmo com captura da tela, uma técnica conhecida é colocar dois ou mais números ou letras em cada botão. É assim em vários caixas eletrônicos.

Mesmo assim, um *malware* específico e mais sofisticado poderia monitorar o valor dos campos do formulário. Para mitigar esse risco, ao invés dos botões do teclado virtual "digitarem" o mesmo número ou letra sendo exibido, o valor poderia ser um símbolo gerado aleatoriamente do lado do servidor para esta sessão. Sendo que o símbolo mudaria a cada acesso do usuário.

Mesmo com tudo isso, um *malware* instalado na máquina ainda poderia obter acessos indevidos, mas certamente o nível de dificuldade e as restrições impostas por estas e outras técnicas podem diminuir riscos de segurança ao aumentar o nível requirido de conhecimento e sofisticação do ataque para concretizar uma "invasão".

Na prática, não tenho dados para dizer o quanto um teclado virtual pode ou não contribuir para melhoria da segurança. Embora muitas instituições financeiras lancem mão deste recurso, empresas mundiais, tal como o PayPal, não o adotam.

Se eu fosse implementar algum mecanismo de autenticação em aplicações de risco, gastaria um bom tempo estudando as soluções existentes e nunca adotaria qualquer solução "pronta" de algum blog ou tutorial.

Comment: Complementando, os softwares espiões que foram sucesso há uns 15 anos atrás, desses que os _script kiddies_ acham fácil na internet, normalmente capturam um retângulo da tela na região do mouse quando você clica, além de gravarem os eventos de teclado. Isso foi no advento do uso dos teclados virtuais pelos "peixes grandes", que deixaram de usar essas soluções justamente por terem perdido a eficácia. Isso confere com a sua observação sobre paypal e outras empresas mundiais.